# Prove Leibniz' rule using three properties

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I get stuck after using the first parameter, on how to expand it using the fundemental theorm of calculus and the chain rule.

Here is the question:

If $\varphi(t) = \int_{g(t)}^{h(t)}f(x,t)dx$, apply the fact that if $g(t) = \int_Af(x,t)dx$ then $g'(t) = \int_AD_2f(x,t)dx $, the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the chain rule to prove Leibniz' rule:

$\varphi'(t) = f(h(t),t)h'(t)-f(g(t),t)g'(t) + \int_{g(t)}^{h(t)}D_2f(x,t)dx$

The first property gets the last term... but It also shows  it is equal to $\varphi'(t)$.

Anyway, thanks for the hints/solutions as alawys

Comment: I forgot to add that $D2$ = d/dt

Comment: I solved it, so no need to answer !

Comment: upsss!! I first wrote the solution and then noted that you had already solved it :D, nevermind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a quite complicated application of Leibniz' rule:$$$$ 
First, of all note that if you consider g and h as variables which are dependent on t, then you obtain: 
$$\phi(t)=\int_g^hf(x,t)dx=\Phi(g,h,t)$$
Now differentiate:
$$\phi'(t)= \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial g}\frac{d g}{dt}+ \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial h}\frac{d h}{dt}+\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}$$

It's easy now to see that :
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial h}=f(h,t), \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial g}=-f(g,t),\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}=\int_g^h\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}dx$$
and combining the above relations we obtain the desired reasult.

Comment: Yes, i solved it very similarly. ill give u the answer points anyway!