# Leibniz Integral Rule Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let
$$
I(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x, y) \mathrm{d} y
$$
for a smooth function $f(x, y)$. Prove that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} I}{\mathrm{~d} x}=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y) \mathrm{d} y+\frac{\mathrm{d} b}{\mathrm{~d} x} f(x, b(x))-\frac{\mathrm{d} a}{\mathrm{~d} x} f(x, a(x)) .
$$
**Hint:** Start by writing $f=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ and then apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to $I(x)$.

Could someone explain how we are able to write f as a partial derivative and how this then allows us to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to I(x)? I assume it is something to do with the fact that we can keep x fixed, but intuitively I'm struggling to understand how it all makes sense.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359199

Does this help?

Comment: Note the smoothness of $f$ is good but we also should need $b,a$ to be differentiable. Smoothness of $f$ is too strong a hypothesis actually. Some online discussions of this rule don't mention that differentiation-under-the-integral-sign doesn't always work...